# Image from URL won't load in ASP.NET View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I've got this view where I want to display an Image but it won't display when I start the site.

f.ImageFilePath contains this string https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDEwZmIzNjYtNjUwNS00MzgzLWJiOGYtZWMxZGQ5NDcxZjUwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIzOTk5ODM@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,728,1000_AL_.jpg

```
@using System.Drawing
@model IEnumerable<BlueRateITLogicLayer.Models.Film>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Films";
}

<h2>Films</h2>

@foreach (var f in @Model)
{
    <div class="">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img scr="@f.ImageFilePath"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                @f.Name
            </div>
            <div class="text-left">
                @f.StoryLine
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Show us the rendered HTML for that `img` tag.

Comment: Probably help if you use `SRC` instead of `SCR`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/29945fc01bf15abb32b7bf0edaa6e210

Comment: @JamieD77 Thank you.... I swear it's always the typos....